# How to batch geoprocess using iteration with tool parameter values in table

Tags: arcpy

As part of my work at a non-profit, I am preparing a map for an upcoming legislative session. GIS is only a small portion of my job. I am comfortable with ArcGIS but have no experience with Python (I do know Java, Visual Basic, and HTML and have a basic understanding of object oriented coding). Here is the issue (that I think can be relatively easily done in Python).

I want to generate a certain number of random points in roughly 1,200 ZCTAs. The number of points corresponds to the client records for that ZCTA. I have a table with the ID for of each ZCTA in the state and the number of client records for that ZCTA. I also have a shp file of all ZCTAs in the state. Given the number of ZCTAs, doing this manually will take too much time.

The table I have has N rows and 2 columns, ID and PointNum. The data table of the ZCTA shp data has one field, GeoID. The table can be joined to the shp with the ID field.

The idea is to generate the correct number of random points in each ZCTA by iterating through the table and setting the parameter of the random point tool to the value of PointNum for the given ZCTA. Here is a conceptual model for how I could do this.

- WHILE x < N
- Select feature in ZCTA shp using table ID field
- Random point tool with extent same as ZCTA shp and number of points = PointNum
- Clear Selection
- N + 1

I have no idea how to implement this (or even if my proposed way makes sense). I seek an example of a python script (with some annotation).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [arcpy data access module search cursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) to obtain your IDs and PointNums:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'path/to/feature/class' #path to input feature class
fields = ["ID","PointNum"] #the fields you want to search
p = r'output/path' #output folder or gdb

scur = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields) #create a searchcursor object, 
#which consists of rows of data.  each row will be a tuple of (ID,PointNum).  there will be N rows.

for row in scur: #iterate scur
    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(p, row[0], fc, '#', row[1]) #create random points for each 
    #row in scur using ID as output name and PointNum as number of points

del scur #delete the cursor to release schema locks
```

I have not tested this.  You may need to cast row[1] as an integer by calling int(row[1]).